# Upload To FTP using Batch Script

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I want to use a batch script to upload a file into my ftp server. I have tried so many scripts mentioned on this website and others, but none of them is working. Please someone guide me step by step passing this.

For example one of those scripts is this:

```
@echo off
echo user USERNAME> ftpcmd.dat
echo PASSWORD>> ftpcmd.dat
echo put %1>> ftpcmd.dat
echo quit>> ftpcmd.dat
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.dat SERVERNAME
del ftpcmd.dat
```

Also I have tried a comd tool named ftpget, but nothing :(

Comment: What scripts have you tried? I bet you don't want people to link them here again. Refer them here.

Comment: Can you upload anything by using just the cmd prompt rather than with a batch file?

Comment: @Bali C windows command line can not detect "FTP" command, it will say it is not recognized. Is there any changes in windows 7 for ftp command?

Comment: It sounds like your `%PATH%` is broken, ftp is definitely in Win7. Type `path` at a cmd prompt and see what paths it has, make sure `C:\Windows\system32` is one of them.

Comment: @BaliC it seems you are right, I have test ftp command on my laptop and it is working fine, Also path command will show C:\Windows\system32 too, but in my PC path command won't show C:\Windows\system32, instead it will show %systemroot%\system32. do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: @Stranger `%systemroot%` is a variable for C:\Windows, but see my answer for full details :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems that your actual script is fine, it's just that the ftp executable can't be found on your Win7 PC.

This is most likely due to a broken `%PATH%` variable. To restore it just edit it with the default values of

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShel l\v1.0\
```

You can edit `%PATH%` by going to Start -> Right click Computer -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables.

Find Path in system variables and edit is as above, which should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have replace the first %SystemRoot% with C:\Windows and now it is working fine, Now I have another question, How to say the script to create and emtpy text file on server? I mean I do not want to send an exiting text file, just want the script make an empty one on server and it is for testing purposes. so how to do it?

Comment: To create an empty file use `echo. >file.txt`. It won't actually contain any data, but it will have a space at the start, as silly as it sounds, I think it's pretty difficult to actually create a file without the space at the front, but this should do fine.

Comment: Just found a way of having no space at the front `type nul >file.txt` :)